# How does neo4j implements text index to support CONTAINS query?

Tags: neo4j

There is an index type called TEXT INDEX in Neo4j which is designed for CONTAINS and END WITH search when I try to create an index in it. In traditional DB, contains query is not recommend, because it is hard to use the index. So I'm confused how Neo4j implements TEXT INDEX to support CONTAINS query.

Here is the screenshot from Neo4j's official site, https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/index-configuration/#index-configuration-text.

[description for TEXT INDEX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cORek.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the TEXT index will only be active in Neo4j 5.

Like the full-text-index it's currently based on [apache lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/). Which uses a number of approaches for fast search, TDF-IDF, document vectors and more.

There might be a new implementation in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
By the way, compare to `wildcard` in `elasticsearch`, `contains` in neo4j is better or not.